# Can I change the "First and last name" field label in Firebase UI Javascript Library?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I want to change this field label from "First and last name" to "Display Name".  The documentation implies it's not possible but maybe I missed something. https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#customizing-firebaseui-for-authentication

If I can't change it I'll just remove it altogether via

```
requireDisplayName: false
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are including `firebaseui.js` from your local server NOT `CDN` server (ie. `<script src="./dist/firebaseui.js"></script>`) than you may edit the local js file [image]

Comment: @user1961 Your wellcome.:)